# Two RDS Endpoints Share same VPN. Can Connect to One but Not the Other From Vagrant Box

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vagrant, vpn, amazon-rds

I have two RDS endpoints: qa-cxx-vpc.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com and, qa-dxx-vpc.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com.

When I ssh into my vagrant box and and try `mysql -uusername2015 -ppassword2015 -hqa-dxx-vpc.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` I can log into mysql.  
If I shut down my host computer vpn client I cannot login. However, when I am logged into the VPN using my host machine, and try my other RDS endpoint `mysql -uusername2015 -ppassword2015 -hqa-cxx-vpc.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com and qa-dxx-vpc.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` I am not able to log in. When I am on my host machine I can log on to both.  
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox by default configures NAT to use 10.0.2.x. The RDS host IP address was in the same 10.0.2.x IP range and thus clashing. By adding 
`vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natnet1", "192.168.100/24"]` to the Vagrantfile, I can now access use my remote RDS instance from Vagrant.